# Logo text to line up with picture

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to get my logo and text to line up on the same line and for some reason it's not happening. Another thing which I am also struggling with, is the fact that my text on the right hand side disappears as I resize the window. 
HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class = "logo">
        <img src="Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        <h1> Logo </h1>
        </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <p>
            Need something ? <a href="#" role="link" id="account_btn">Create it now</a>
            </p>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url("Images/a.jpg");
    padding-top: 58px;
}

.navbar-brand{
     margin-left:50px !important;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}


.navbar-right {
    margin-top: 63px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you drop a fiddle, it'd be way easier to help you out?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32930/ As you can see when u shrink the screen, it make the text disappear x

Comment: Your biggest issue is not using the navbar elements in it's entirety. You are missing a lot of markup. The navbar elemets are displaying non, as it's collapsing into a hamburger menu. Please review [Bootstraps navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for both `img` and `h4`.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zy8tdbtu/

```
.logo img{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.logo h1{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

**Updated**

Is is bcoz you have used the `collapse` class which hide the `navbar-right` when you shrink the screen. Remove that class.

here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zy8tdbtu/1/

Comment: Ah that fixed the logo part but my text on the right side is still not showing when u make it smaller

Comment: Can you add the online url of your logo image in your code so that i can see the exact problem

Comment: its not the logo part its the "Dont have an account ? Create your account" , when u shrink the window it disappears completely

Answer (score 0):

My advice to you is to actually use **Bootstrap**'s GRID system. That's why it's so powerful for building responsive designs. I solved your problem by inserting `col` spacing inside the header such as: `col-md-8 col-xs-8` and `col-md-4 col-xs-4`. My advice is to read about how to work with columns actually.

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32933/)

Answer (score 0):

That's just your right sidebar of nav links collapsing down into the Hamburger menu for mobile navigation. You can't see the hamburger because it's black on a black background.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest researching what bootstrap (and any other css framework) is actually doing when you throw in those class names. You've added `navbar-collapse` which will hide the navbar and display it as a hamburger menu (if the markup is there) without knowing what it does, leading to your confusion.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

CSS frameworks are great tools when you really understand whats going on under the hood